# Exactly what is the 'Ctrl' argument in the click handler for a CommandBarButton?

Tags: c#, com, event-handling, com-interop, commandbar

I recently <s>fixed</s> *worked around* a very annoying issue in my code base.

I have a `ParentMenuItemBase` abstract class from which I derive classes that essentially wrap a `CommandBarPopup` control, and create the child `CommandBarButton` objects and wire up their `Click` event to execute an `ICommand`.

Say I had a `RefactorRenameCommand` hooked up to 5 completely independent `CommandBarButton` objects, under 5 completely unrelated `CommandBarPopup` controls.

When I clicked the `CommandBarButton`, the `child_Click` handler would then run 5 times - and the `Ctrl` parameter would have the same hash code for all 5 "clicks".

Then if I clicked the same button again, the handler would again run 5 times, and again the `Ctrl` parameter would have the same hash code for all 5 "clicks", ...but the hash code would be different from what it was the first time around - and if I clicked again, I'd get a new hash code for that parameter.

I obtained the desired behavior by storing the last hash code for that `Ctrl` parameter in a `private static` field, and only executing the handler if the hash code for `Ctrl` was different - in other words, I made it work by building on top of an observed behavior that I didn't completely understand, and it feels dirty and it bothers me beyond words. Here's the hack in question, including the actual in-code comments:

```
// note: HAAAAACK!!!
private static int _lastHashCode;

private void child_Click(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
    var item = _items.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).SingleOrDefault(menu => menu.Key == Ctrl.Tag) as ICommandMenuItem;
    if (item == null || Ctrl.GetHashCode() == _lastHashCode)
    {
        return;
    }

    // without this hack, handler runs once for each menu item that's hooked up to the command.
    // hash code is different on every frakkin' click. go figure. I've had it, this is the fix.
    _lastHashCode = Ctrl.GetHashCode();

    Debug.WriteLine("({0}) Executing click handler for menu item '{1}', hash code {2}", GetHashCode(), Ctrl.Caption, Ctrl.GetHashCode());
    item.Command.Execute(null);
}
```

That `Debug.WriteLine` call would output something like this:

> ```
> (46595510) Executing click handler for menu item '&Rename', hash code 16706408
> (16139946) Executing click handler for menu item '&Rename', hash code 16706408
> (11041789) Executing click handler for menu item '&Rename', hash code 16706408
> (32267243) Executing click handler for menu item '&Rename', hash code 16706408
> (21969731) Executing click handler for menu item '&Rename', hash code 16706408
> ```

And the next click would produce an identical output, except with a different hash code for the `Ctrl` parameter.

So, exactly what is this `Ctrl` parameter? If it's the `CommandBarButton` COM control that was clicked, then why does its hash code not match that of the `CommandBarButton` object I created? And why does its hash code change every time the handler runs?

Comment: Well, [the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa170943(v=office.11).aspx) isn't much help. It pretty much says what you'd expect...